# NumPy MemoryError when using array constructors

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, constructor

I'm creating a couple of arrays using numpy and list constructors, and I can't figure out why this is failing. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ndarray( [i for i in range(10)] ) # works fine
B = np.ndarray( [i**2 for i in range(10)] ) # fails, with MemoryError
```

I've also tried just `B = [i**2 for i in range(10)]` which works, but I need it to be an ndarray. I don't see why the normal constructor would work but calling a function wouldn't. As far as I understand, the ndarray constructor shouldn't even see the inside of that, it should get a length 10 list with ints in it for both.

Comment: Use `np.array([...])`.  `np.ndarray` is an advanced constructor with different parameters.  `np.array` is the one we normally use.

Comment: Or use `np.zeros` (or `ones` or `empty`) if trying to create an array with a list of dimensions.

Comment: As @hpaulj suggests, normally you should use `np.array()` to create a new array from a list.  The first argument of `ndarray` is the *shape* of the array, not the data to put in the array.  So you are requesting an array with shape `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`.  It is interesting that it generates a `MemoryError`.  With that 0 in there, the total size of the array would actually be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html is a low-level method that we normally don't use.  Its first argument is the `shape`.

```
In [98]: np.ndarray([x for x in range(3)])
Out[98]: array([], shape=(0, 1, 2), dtype=float64)
In [99]: np.ndarray([x**2 for x in range(3)])
Out[99]: array([], shape=(0, 1, 4), dtype=float64)
```

Normally use `zeros` or `ones` to construct a blank array of a given shape:

```
In [100]: np.zeros([x**2 for x in range(3)])
Out[100]: array([], shape=(0, 1, 4), dtype=float64)
```

Use `np.array` if you want to turn a list into an array:

```
In [101]: np.array([x for x in range(3)])
Out[101]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [102]: np.array([x**2 for x in range(3)])
Out[102]: array([0, 1, 4])
```

You can generate the range numbers, and then perform the math on the whole array (without iteration):

```
In [103]: np.arange(3)**2
Out[103]: array([0, 1, 4])
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I knew the type was ndarray so I assumed that would be the constructor.